# Trouble Displaying Values From Firebase Using Ionic

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know Angular very well, and I'm trying to create a simple game information page using data I have in firebase. I've loaded the data onto the page via my getData function on page load. I can see the values output in the console, but when I try to call them in the HTML, I'm coming up blank.

The values I'm using to call the data are the same as I'm using elsewhere, but I can't seem to figure out how to cal them here. Help?

Here is what the console is outputting:

```
Object
game: "Football"
description: "24 people for 12 v 12. 40 minutes. "
image: "https://ionicframework.com/dist/preview-app/www/assets/img/advance-card-map-madison.png"
location: "Austin"
players: "24"
id: "99rnLdx7gk4rCniE1yrq"
```

Here is the top of my ts file / function writing the data to the console:

```
import { NavController, ModalController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';
import { UserDetailsPage } from '../user-details/user-details';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-game-info',
  templateUrl: 'game-info.html'
})

export class GameInfoPage {

  items: Array<any>;
  item: any;
  value: any;
  id: any;
  data: Array<any>;


  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService
  ) {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    let data = this.navParams.get('data');

    console.log(data);
  }
```

Finally, here is my HTML file:

```
<ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
          <ion-title center>Game Info</ion-title>

          <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="logout()">
                <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>
              </button>
          </ion-buttons>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
          <ion-content class="list-mini-content">

            <div text-center>
              <ion-img class="prof-img" src="../../assets/imgs/30073571_10156282406987329_8843328631007804748_o.jpg"></ion-img>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let item of items" text-center>
              <h2 center>{{item().game}}</h2>
                    <ion-item padding>
                    <p>{{data().location}}</p>
                    <button ion-button icon-start clear item-end (click)="viewUserDetails(item.payload.doc.id,item.payload.doc.data())">
                      <ion-icon name="create" ></ion-icon> Edit
                    </button>
                  </ion-item>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-item padding>
                    <span>{{item.payload.doc.data()}}</span>
                    <button ion-button icon-start clear item-end>
                      <ion-icon name="navigate"></ion-icon>
                      Join
                    </button>
                  </ion-item>
                  </ion-row>
                </div>
          </ion-content>

          <ion-footer>

             </ion-footer>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are displaying items array in your template but initialising data array in your component

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
getData(){
    let data = this.navParams.get('data');

    console.log(data);
  }
```

Into this:

```
getData(){
    this.data = this.navParams.get('data');

    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

`data` needs to be an instance variable to be able to use it in the template.

Also change:

```
<h2 center>{{item().game}}</h2>
                    <ion-item padding>
                    <p>{{data().location}}</p>
```

Into this:

```
<h2 center>{{item.game}}</h2>
                    <ion-item padding>
                    <p>{{data.location}}</p>
```

Both `item` and `data` are properties, therefore you don't need to add `()`